# How to download files using PhoneGap and retrieve them back to jQuery Mobile?

Tags: jquery, cordova, mobile

I have done some research(please correct me if I'm wrong) and understand that while I can use PhoneGap's FileSystem API to download files from a remote server, they are being saved to a location which the jQuery Mobile has no access to. Also, they can't be downloaded to the "www" folder, which belongs to the jQuery mobile as well.

I'm trying to download updated html codes/snippet from my server and inject into my jquery mobile app as a new page or as a package of pages, possibly by adding a couple of divs with "data-role=page" or something..

Thanks for the help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Use full code snippet for download file:

```
    function downloadFile(){

window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, 
    function onFileSystemSuccess(fileSystem) {
        fileSystem.root.getFile(
        "dummy.html", {create: true, exclusive: false}, 
        function gotFileEntry(fileEntry) {
            var sPath = fileEntry.fullPath.replace("dummy.html","");
            var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
            fileEntry.remove();

            fileTransfer.download(
                "http://www.w3.org/2011/web-apps-ws/papers/Nitobi.pdf",
                sPath + "theFile.pdf",
                function(theFile) {
                    console.log("download complete: " + theFile.toURI());
                    //load your updated files
                },
                function(error) {
                    console.log("download error source " + error.source);
                    console.log("download error target " + error.target);
                    console.log("upload error code: " + error.code);
                }
            );
        }, fail);
    }, fail);
};
}
```

You could replace the "dummy.html" with your page which needs to be updated.

Then replace "http://www.w3.org/2011/web-apps-ws/papers/Nitobi.pdf" with the updated package from the remote server.

Finally just load your updated file. :)